# Install/use pip for specific version/location of python

Tags: python, pip

For whatever lame reason, I have a bunch of different versions of python installed. The one I want to use (and what my current $PATH is using) is at /opt/python2.6/bin/python. How do I install 'pip' for this version so when I do a 'pip install package' it goes to the right location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple versions of Python with pip installed, you can launch pip using your Python executable:

```
$python2.6 -m pip [pip-args]
```

To install pip for a specific Python version, run `get-pip.py` (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) with the respective Python executable:

```
$python2.6 get-pip.py
```

Comment: This is what I get when I do that: /opt/python2.6/bin/python: No module named pip. I'm assuming that's because I don't have a version of pip installed for that version of python, right?

Comment: @user3693009 Yes. You should be able to install pip using the get-pip.py bootstrap script. See my updated answer.